# Google calendar wrong date issue from URL

Tags: php, url, calendar

SO here is the problem ... I had created calendar on http://lanyrd.com with same dates but for some reason, my code is showing dates "from" and "to" on the same date, and other (from Lanyrd site) is showing dates correctly and I can't figure it out why ... Can someone help me?

Lanyrd site generated URL code:

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=Test+Naziv&dates=20120815/20120817&location=Osijek&details=Ajme+meni+ovo+je+test+naziv&pli=1&sf=true&output=xml
```

Mine code:

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=eZ+Publish+Basic+Concepts&dates=20121008/20121009&location=TBD,+USA&details=This+training+is+required+for+all+other+trainings+and+provides+a+perfect+entry+into+the+way+of+thinking+when+you+intend+working+with+eZ+Publish+as+a+developer,+editor+or+administrator.&pli=1&sf=true&output=xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, checking the URL's, I would say Google Agenda takes the 'to'-date minus one. As you can see in Lanyrd's URL: dates=20120815/20120817

It's two days apart, but in Google Agenda it shows as 2012-08-16. Your dates are only one apart, so will enter the same date. Plus-one your to-date, and you're problem is solved.

Comment: It seems so ... After hours of trying to find solutions I was so blind ... Thanks!